# How can I refractory mapping in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to refractory my codes in react, I have to duplicate code to make it works.

Here is my following code:

```
<div className="team-invitees-tab-panes">
  {!loading &&
    currentInvitee.invited.accepted &&
    tabs[activeTab] === "Pending" &&
    invitees.map((user, index) => (
      <div
        role="button"
        className={
          selected === index
            ? "member-list-item-container selected"
            : index === selected - 1
            ? "member-list-item-container border-none"
            : "member-list-item-container"
        }
        tabIndex={index}
        key={`member-${index}`}
        onClick={() => handleSelect(index)}
        onKeyPress={() => {
          return;
        }}
      >
        <div className="member-list-item">
          <div
            className="avatar"
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${user.picture})` }}
          />
          <div className="name">{user.fullname}</div>
          <div className="status">
            <svg
              width="12"
              height="16"
              viewBox="0 0 12 16"
              fill="none"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <path
                d="M11.1836 4.90431C11.338 4.79611 11.4632 4.65656 11.5496 4.49648C11.636 4.33641 11.6812 4.16012 11.6817 3.98132V1.40406C11.6813 1.09731"
                fill="#102A42"
              />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
  {!loading &&
    currentInvitee.invited.declined &&
    tabs[activeTab] === "Declined" &&
    invitees.map((user, index) => (
      <div
        role="button"
        className={
          selected === index
            ? "member-list-item-container selected"
            : index === selected - 1
            ? "member-list-item-container border-none"
            : "member-list-item-container"
        }
        tabIndex={index}
        key={`member-${index}`}
        onClick={() => handleSelect(index)}
        onKeyPress={() => {
          return;
        }}
      >
        <div className="member-list-item">
          <div
            className="avatar"
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${user.picture})` }}
          />
          <div className="name">{user.fullname}</div>
          <div className="status">
            <svg
              width="12"
              height="16"
              viewBox="0 0 12 16"
              fill="none"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <path
                d="M11.1836 4.90431C11.338 4.79611 11.4632 4.65656 11.5496 4.49648C11.636 4.33641 11.6812 4.16012 11.6817 3.98132V1.40406C11.6813 1.09731"
                fill="#102A42"
              />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Here is my photo of how my code looks like in web page

[image]

Is there anything that help me not to duplicate code for pending, accepted and declined?

Thank you so much for helping me, I really appreaciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make sepatare component `Invitation` which would render element of invites

```
const Invite = ({ user, selected, index, handleSelect }) => {
  return (
    <div
      role="button"
      className={
        selected === index
          ? "member-list-item-container selected"
          : index === selected - 1
          ? "member-list-item-container border-none"
          : "member-list-item-container"
      }
      tabIndex={index}
      key={`member-${index}`}
      onClick={() => handleSelect(index)}
      onKeyPress={() => {
        return;
      }}
    >
      <div className="member-list-item">
        <div
          className="avatar"
          style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${user.picture})` }}
        />
        <div className="name">{user.fullname}</div>
        <div className="status">
          <svg
            width="12"
            height="16"
            viewBox="0 0 12 16"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <path
              d="M11.1836 4.90431C11.338 4.79611 11.4632 4.65656 11.5496 4.49648C11.636 4.33641 11.6812 4.16012 11.6817 3.98132V1.40406C11.6813 1.09731"
              fill="#102A42"
            />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and use it like

```
<div className="team-invitees-tab-panes">
  {!loading &&
    currentInvitee.invited.accepted &&
    tabs[activeTab] === 'Pending' &&
    invitees.map((user, index) => (
      <Invite
        index={index}
        user={user}
        handleSelect={handleSelect}
        selected={selected}
      />
    ))}
  {!loading &&
    currentInvitee.invited.declined &&
    tabs[activeTab] === 'Declined' &&
    invitees.map((user, index) => (
      <Invite
        index={index}
        user={user}
        handleSelect={handleSelect}
        selected={selected}
      />
    ))}
</div>
```

also it looks like you are using `invitees` array for each tab, is it going to change to seprate arrays in the future?

Comment: Yes it will change seperate array in the future